# Why is Jest producing different codes in the snapshot created for the same component?

Tags: testing, jestjs

So I am testing a Login component using the create function from react-test-renderer and I am trying to test the onPress function of a custom component within the Login Function called SuperButton. I am attempting to do so by passing a testId as a prop to the SuperButton and locating it using the findByProps function. I have two SuperButton components within the Login component.

Another extra information is that the SuperButton component returns a ToucableOpacity component

Why is it that when the snapshot is generated, the first SuperButton is generated as such :-

```
<SuperButton
                      btnMode="PrimaryButton"
                      onPress={[Function]}
                      refArray={
                        [
                          undefined,
                        ]
                      }
                      testID="button"
                      txtMode="PrimaryButtonText"
                      validate={false}
                    >
                      LblYesItIs
                    </SuperButton>
```

The second SuperButton is generated as such :-

```
<View
              accessible={true}
              focusable={true}
              onClick={[Function]}
              onResponderGrant={[Function]}
              onResponderMove={[Function]}
              onResponderRelease={[Function]}
              onResponderTerminate={[Function]}
              onResponderTerminationRequest={[Function]}
              onStartShouldSetResponder={[Function]}
              style={
                {
                  "alignItems": "center",
                  "backgroundColor": "transparent",
                  "justifyContent": "center",
                  "marginRight": "2%",
                  "marginTop": "2%",
                  "opacity": 1,
                  "width": "10%",
                }
              }
            >
```

The issue when it is rendered as the second one is that I am unable to locate the testId given to SuperButton so ideally I want it to render as the first one. How can I do so?

I have tried using different methods to render the snapshot but I am still experiencing the same issue.